# How do you retry API call several times before failing it?

Tags: javascript, typescript, axios

I have some code like below. Is there an easy way to make it try the endpoint 3 times before finally giving up and sending it to the catch block? The last code block would be an untested attempt but I am wondering if there are more appropriate ways to handle this.

This file is shared with react mobile and web. I am using the web side and would not like to alter this file.

```
import { AxiosResponse } from 'axios';
import { HttpClient } from '../..';

export function postTeam({
  userId,
}: {
  userId: number;
}): Promise<AxiosResponse<TeamDetail>> {
  return HttpClient.post(
    `teams`,
    {
      user: {
        id: userId,
      },
    },
    {
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
      },
    },
  );
}
```

And a file that calls this code like this. This is where I would like to make the changes as this is only on the web side of the code....

```
postTeam({
    userId: user.id,
})
.then(() => {
    //Do something
})
.catch((errors) => {
    console.log(errors);
    trackApiError(new Error(errors));
})
.finally(() => setIsSubmitting(false));
```

My attempt:

```
for(let x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
  let success = false;
  postTeam({
    userId: user.id,
  })
    .then(() => {
      success = true;
    })
    .catch((errors) => {
      if(x >= 2) {
        console.log(errors);
        trackApiError(new Error(errors));
      }
    })
    .finally(() => {
      setIsSubmitting(false);
      success = true;
    })
    if(success) break;
}
```

Comment: There are packages axios-retry and retry-axios for exactly this purpose, would one of those work for you?

Comment: Just an FYI, your custom request headers are redundant

Comment: @ZacAnger How would this look with my code here? Sorry for being a noob but they are all using `axios.get` and calling axios directly. This is code I have inherited.

Comment: Can you add the code for the `HttpClient` function? That's probably what will need to be wrapped. Most likely you can use axios-retry by wrapping your HttpClient and calling `HttpClient.post` like normal, assuming your HttpClient is just an axios instance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer this question a little bit broadly, but can still easily be applied to your situation. What I'm going to be answering is how to retry something when failing means throwing an error.

```js
const maxTries = 3
let i = 0
do {
    try {
        // What you want to attempt. "await"ing if it returns a promise.
        break
    } catch { }
    ++i
} while (i < maxTries)
```

This is personally the way I'd probably do it as it means slightly less calculations. I'm betting many would disagree with me though saying the optimisation is insignificant, and I'd agree with them so this is probably the easy way, readability wise.

```js
const maxTries = 3
for (let i = 0; i < maxTries; ++i)
    try {
        // What you want to attempt. "await"ing if it returns a promise.
        break
    }
    catch (e) { console.error(e) }
```